# Query becomes slow when two conditions are both applied

Tags: mysql, sql, performance, query-optimization

I have a `users` table with `bio` field and "n:n" relationship with itself via the `followers` table so each user `U` can follow many other users. My user search query is super slow.

1. All queries get the first 20 search results (`limit 20`).
2. Searching for users who have "founder" in their bio takes 0.3s.
3. searching for users who follow X takes 0.03s.
4. Searching for users who have "founder" in their bio AND follow X takes 118s.

Query for both filters:

```
select distinct `twitter_user`.`id`
from `twitter_user`
         join `twitter_user_follower`
              on (
                          `twitter_user_follower`.`follower_twitter_user_id` =
                          `twitter_user`.`id`
                      and `twitter_user_follower`.`twitter_user_id` = 4899565692
                      and `twitter_user_follower`.`follower_download_id` = 7064
                  )
where MATCH(twitter_user.description) AGAINST('founder')
limit 20 offset 0
```

Table definitions :

```
CREATE TABLE `twitter_user` (
  `id` bigint NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(128) DEFAULT NULL,
  `screen_name` varchar(128) DEFAULT NULL,
  `location` varchar(256) DEFAULT NULL,
  `description` varchar(512) DEFAULT NULL,
  `url` varchar(256) DEFAULT NULL,
  `is_protected` bit(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `followers_count` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `is_verified` bit(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `friends_count` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_at` bigint DEFAULT NULL,
  `favourites_count` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `utc_offset` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `time_zone` varchar(128) DEFAULT NULL,
  `statuses_count` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `profile_image_url` varchar(512) DEFAULT NULL,
  `internal_json` json DEFAULT NULL,
  `row_timestamp` timestamp NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `twitter_user_username_index` (`screen_name`),
  KEY `twitter_user_ts` (`row_timestamp`),
  FULLTEXT KEY `twitter_user_description_ft_index` (`description`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci;

CREATE TABLE `twitter_user_follower` (
  `id` bigint NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `twitter_user_id` bigint NOT NULL,
  `follower_twitter_user_id` bigint NOT NULL,
  `created_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `follower_download_id` bigint DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `twitter_user_follower_twitter_user_id_index` (`twitter_user_id`),
  KEY `twitter_user_follower_follower_download_id_index` (`follower_download_id`),
  KEY `tuf_twitter_user_follower_download_key` (`twitter_user_id`,`follower_download_id`,`follower_twitter_user_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=68494675 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci;
```

`Explain` output :

| id | select_type | table | partitions | type | possible_keys | key | key_len | ref | rows | filtered | Extra |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | SIMPLE | twitter_user | NULL | fulltext | PRIMARY,twitter_user_username_index,twitter_user_ts,twitter_user_description_ft_index | twitter_user_description_ft_index | 0 | const | 1 | 100.00 | Using where; Ft_hints: no_ranking; Using temporary |
| 1 | SIMPLE | twitter_user_follower | NULL | ref | twitter_user_follower_twitter_user_id_index,twitter_user_follower_follower_download_id_index,tuf_twitter_user_follower_download_key | tuf_twitter_user_follower_download_key | 25 | const,const,si_data_db.twitter_user.id | 1 | 100.00 | Using index; Distinct |

Tree output:

```
-> Limit: 20 row(s)  (cost=4.77..4.77 rows=1)
-> Table scan on <temporary>  (cost=2.51..2.51 rows=1)
    -> Temporary table with deduplication  (cost=4.77..4.77 rows=1)
        -> Limit table size: 20 unique row(s)
            -> Nested loop inner join  (cost=2.16 rows=1)
                -> Filter: (match twitter_user.`description` against (''founder''))  (cost=1.06 rows=1)
                    -> Full-text index search on twitter_user using twitter_user_description_ft_index (description=''founder'')  (cost=1.06 rows=1)
                -> Limit: 1 row(s)  (cost=1.10 rows=1)
                    -> Covering index lookup on twitter_user_follower using tuf_twitter_user_follower_download_key (twitter_user_id=4899565692, follower_download_id=7064, follower_twitter_user_id=twitter_user.id)  (cost=1.10 rows=1)
```

This query is still slow:

```sql
SELECT `follower`.`follower_twitter_user_id`
FROM (
         SELECT `follower_twitter_user_id`
         FROM `twitter_user_follower`
         WHERE `twitter_user_id` = 4899565692
           AND `follower_download_id` = 7440
     ) AS follower
         JOIN `twitter_user` ON `follower`.`follower_twitter_user_id` =  `twitter_user`.`id`
WHERE MATCH(twitter_user.description) AGAINST('+founder' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
limit 20 offset 0;
```

`Explain` output:

| id | select_type | table | partitions | type | possible_keys | key | key_len | ref | rows | filtered | Extra |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | SIMPLE | twitter_user | NULL | fulltext | PRIMARY,twitter_user_description_ft_index | twitter_user_description_ft_index | 0 | const | 1 | 100.00 | Using where; Ft_hints: no_ranking |
| 1 | SIMPLE | twitter_user_follower | NULL | ref | twitter_user_follower_twitter_user_id_index,twitter_user_follower_follower_download_id_index,tuf_twitter_user_follower_download_key | tuf_twitter_user_follower_download_key | 25 | const,const,si_data_db.twitter_user.id | 1 | 100.00 | Using index |

`Explain` Analyze output:

```
-> Limit: 20 row(s)  (cost=2.16 rows=1) (actual time=3779.933..91032.297 rows=20 loops=1)
    -> Nested loop inner join  (cost=2.16 rows=1) (actual time=3779.932..91032.285 rows=20 loops=1)
        -> Filter: (match twitter_user.`description` against ('+founder' in boolean mode))  (cost=1.06 rows=1) (actual time=94.166..90001.280 rows=198818 loops=1)
            -> Full-text index search on twitter_user using twitter_user_description_ft_index (description='+founder')  (cost=1.06 rows=1) (actual time=94.163..89909.371 rows=198818 loops=1)
        -> Covering index lookup on twitter_user_follower using tuf_twitter_user_follower_download_key (twitter_user_id=4899565692, follower_download_id=7440, follower_twitter_user_id=twitter_user.id)  (cost=1.10 rows=1) (actual time=0.005..0.005 rows=0 loops=198818)
```

`users` table is 125GB and `followers` table is 5GB on disk. If I convert query to two selects joined, it runs in 45s:

```sql
select t1.id from
(select follower_twitter_user_id as id from `twitter_user_follower`
 where (
                   `twitter_user_follower`.`twitter_user_id` = 4899565692
               and `twitter_user_follower`.`follower_download_id` = 8039
           )) t1
inner join
(
    select `twitter_user`.`id`
    from `twitter_user` where MATCH(twitter_user.description) AGAINST('+create' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
) t2 on t1.id = t2.id
limit 20 offset 0
```

`Explain` output:

```
 -> Limit: 20 row(s)  (cost=2.18 rows=1)
    -> Nested loop inner join  (cost=2.18 rows=1)
        -> Filter: (match twitter_user.`description` against ('+create' in boolean mode))  (cost=1.08 rows=1)
            -> Full-text index search on twitter_user using twitter_user_description_ft_index (description='+create')  (cost=1.08 rows=1)
        -> Covering index lookup on twitter_user_follower using tuf_twitter_user_follower_download_key (twitter_user_id=4899565692, follower_download_id=8039, follower_twitter_user_id=twitter_user.id)  (cost=1.10 rows=1)
```

Why does it take 45s to run?

Comment: Since you're using a `LIMIT` without an `ORDER BY`, I'm not surprised that the search with additional conditions could possibly take much longer, even though you seem to have reasonable indexes for this query. I wonder if rewriting this as an `IN` query (without the `JOIN`) might help, but I am only speculating.

Comment: I have been using both `JOIN` and `IN` but both have been slow. I thought `LIMIT` without `ORDER BY` is better for performance as DBMS doesn't need to sort, just pick the first 20 rows it gets.

Comment: I did not mean to imply that adding an `ORDER BY` would improve performance. I merely meant that an `ORDER BY` would probably make the queries with one condition more similar in performance to the query with both conditions, so I'm not completely surprised the numbers are so different in your actual scenario.

Answer (score 2):

Try the following.  CHange

```
MATCH(twitter_user.description) AGAINST('founder')
```

to

```
MATCH(twitter_user.description) AGAINST('+founder' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

Also, the `DISTINCT` may not be necessary.

**IODKU?**

Buried in a comment I see a `DELETE` + `INSERT` that makes for a lot of churn in part of the table.

- InnoDB's FULLTEXT *may not* be efficient in such cases
- If most of the rows aren't changing, then the delete+insert is inefficient and cause more churn than may be necessary.

Look at `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ...` to see if that can be used instead of the delete+insert.  If most of the rows don't change, then this will probably be faster and probably have less impact on things such as the Fulltext index.

If that Delete does actually remove some rows, then the IODKU (upsert) won't suffice.  A second pass using something like `INSERT ... SELECT ... LEFT JOIN` may be the solution for inserting "new" rows.  (I allude to such in a different context here: [*Normalization*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/staging_table#normalization); see SQL#1.)

Periodically (weekly?), run `OPTIMIZE TABLE`.  But keep some timings to see if this step really helps.

**2 steps**

First, I am still unclear about the data you receive every hour.  Is it just info about one user?  Does it include rows to delete with some indication that they are to be deleted instead of updated?  Etc.

If it is a single user...

- `DELETE` only the rows that need deleting.  This involves a multi-table Delete with a `LEFT JOIN` to see what is missing.
- `INSERT ... SELECT ... LEFT JOIN ...` to either insert or update the existing rows.

Comment: Thanks @Rick James. This takes ~78s to run which is an improvement.

Comment: @Mahdi - Ugh! 78s is still terrible.  I added some more thoughts.

Comment: sorry just saw your question. Basically it is a refresh of followers of user X. So every time I get a raw list of followers via an API. I delete all existing follower rows (A) for user X and insert newly received data from API (B). Obviously, most of those rows are the same across `A` and `B`, a few new followers in `B`  (new rows) and a few unfollowers (rows in `A` that don't show up in `B`).

Comment: @Mahdi - Since most of the rows do not need to be replaced, avoiding the blanket `DELETE` should help a lot.

Comment: unfortunately that's not possible as I need the diffs (new people added vs. people removed across new and old series of followers)

Comment: @Mahdi - I'm confused.  Is it Step 1: present the diffs; Step 2 is delete?  If so, let's approach it that way.  That is, work on optimizing each step independently.  I still think the 78s should be fixable.

Answer (score 1):

can you please try this and post the EXPLAIN to us.

```
SELECT `follower`.`follower_twitter_user_id`
FROM (
  SELECT `follower_twitter_user_id`
  FROM `twitter_user_follower`
  WHERE `twitter_user_id` = 4899565692
    AND `follower_download_id` = 7064
) AS follower
JOIN `twitter_user` ON `follower`.`follower_twitter_user_id` =  `twitter_user`.`id`
MATCH(twitter_user.description) AGAINST('+founder' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
limit 20 offset 0;
```

Comment: This one took 115s too. I had to update the `7064` id as new follower downloads deprecate and delete old ones.

Comment: I have updated the question with analyze output. I regularly (each 1h) remove all rows with follower_download_id=X and insert new ones with a new download result. Do you think that might cause an issue?

Comment: @Mahdi - Big delete involving `FULLTEXT`?  This may be a rare case where `OPTIMIZE TABLE` is called for.  Caution: It may block usage of the table while it is running.

Comment: @RickJames This doesn't happen for users table. It happens for `followers` table. So I "refresh" followers every ~1 hours. As a result, most of the rows are the same, some are new and some are no longer following. But what I do is just delete everything from previous download, and insert new ones. Would that cause this slow down? Maybe by fragmenting the table on physical storage?

Comment: A big delete is very intensive since it needs to hang onto the deleted rows until `COMMIT` time.

Comment: The `DELETE` command runs separately at a different time. At the time of query we have all the data. My suspicion is that because I "insert" and "delete" a lot on this table, it makes query slow when follows X is mixed with a full-text search clause.

Comment: If you're deleting Everything in a table, use TRUNCATE instead.

Comment: If you're deleting all rows associated with one user or download (but keep most other rows), don't do that; delete only the necessary rows to prevent (as you suggest) fragmentation.

Comment: That's correct @MatBailie I don't delete the whole table. Only rows associated with a specific `user_id`. The thing is, right now, I blindly `DELETE FROM T WHERE user_id=123` and then again insert new rows while there are like 99% overlap between deleted and inserted rows. I should only delete/insert changed rows.

Comment: Having said that, I'm not sure how much this will help with my search query performance

Comment: @mahdi Deleting and reinserting rows that actually have not changed will cause heavy fragmentation of both table pages and index pages, not to mention hammer log files, etc. Just. Don't. Do. That. If you're not sure of the relative benefit, test it. You do have test and development environments, don't you? Where you can run the import files through as often as you like? (Also, asking for advice, then dismissing that advice kind of makes the first question pointless, wasting everyone's time)

Comment: @mahdi Try this in a slow running tat environment and see if it improves anything. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-file-defragmenting.html

Answer (score 1):

An option to try, in an attempt to minimise overheads and maximise any short-circuiting

```
SELECT
   `twitter_user`.`id`
FROM
  `twitter_user`
WHERE
  MATCH(twitter_user.description) AGAINST ('+founder' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
  AND
  EXISTS (
    SELECT
      *
    FROM
      `twitter_user_follower`
    WHERE
          `follower_twitter_user_id` = `twitter_user`.`id
      AND `twitter_user_id` = 4899565692
      AND `follower_download_id` = 7064
  )
LIMIT 20
OFFSET 0
```